# How to output slope parameter and shape parameter in WRF?

Tags: models, clouds, wrf, radiative-transfer

I'd like to ask if it's possible to output slope parameter and shape parameter of cloud hydrometeors in WRF?

I'm calculating cloud effective radius and I'm using the formula found in Morrison scheme which involves slope and shape parameters. There are calculations for these parameters as well in the scheme, however, I don't think I should be using that calculations to derive these parameters as I think that calculation is done during the "process" aka when the model is running which gives the final values of the parameters. So if I use the calculation again, it will change the outputted values, if you get what I mean?

I'd be happy to re-explain it again if it's not clear. I'm only just starting to get into radiative transfer calculation so my knowledge is still low in this area, therefore I very much appreciate your input/replies.

Comment: Have you tried adding the variable to the registry and outputing the slope parameters from the module?

Comment: Hi @BarocliniCplusplus, no I haven't but I've looked it up and found someone explained how to add it to the registry [here](http://forum.wrfforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3514) . However, I'm unsure of some things. 

1. Do I add the new variable in the driver or the microphysics code?
2. (just confirming) It should be only 1D (kts:kte) instead of the 2D (ims:ime,jms:jme) as he wrote right?
3. In the third step, does the 'subroutine call mp_thompson' refer to the one in the driver?
4. In fourth step, is mp_gt_driver the same as module_microphysics_driver?

Comment: Honestly, i am not all that certain- I have yet to actually add a variable to the registry or change the mp code, but I know that is the way to go if you want output. Sorry I couldn't be much more help.